# Problem with R shiny dashboard and multiple rows

Tags: r, shiny

My apologies if the question is trivial but I am fairly new to R shiny and want to develop a tool to show several histogram plots in two rows, one in the first row and three in the second row. When I plot this in only one row it works, but when I add the sHere is a minimal working code, I appreciate your help with this:

````
pacman::p_load(tidyverse, tidyr, shiny, shinydashboard)


data <- as.data.frame(mtcars)

ui <- dashboardPage(
  skin = "yellow",
  dashboardHeader(title = "My dashboard"),
  dashboardSidebar(
    sidebarMenu()
  ),
  dashboardBody(
    fluidRow(
      box(title = "Primary Metric:", status = "primary", solidHeader = T, plotOutput("CPlot"), width = 7),
      box(selectInput("metric", 
                      "Metric:", 
                      c("mpg",  "cyl", "hp", "wt")),  
          width = 3
      )
    ),
    fluidRow(
      box(title = "Sub-Metric1", width = 4,  status = "warning", solidHeader = T, plotOutput("CPlot")),
      box(title = "Sub-Metric2", width = 4,  status = "warning", solidHeader = T, plotOutput("CPlot")),
      box(title = "Sub-Metric3", width = 4,  status = "warning", solidHeader = T, plotOutput("CPlot"))
    )
  )
)




server <- function(input, output){
  
  # plot
  output$CPlot <- renderPlot({
    ggplot(data, aes(x=data[[input$metric]])) +
      geom_histogram(fill="#D55E00", color="#e9ecef", alpha=0.9) +
      labs(
        title = paste0("Distribution of ", paste0(input$metric), " over the last 12 month"),
        x = req(input$metric),
        y = "Count") +
      theme_minimal()
  })
}


shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server) ```
````

Comment: "When I plot this in only one row it works, but when I add the sHere is a minimal working code": please edit your question to describe the problem clearly.  if you expect four different plots to appear, you need to create four different `plotOutput`s, each with a different id and each with a corresponding call to `renderPlot`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason for this behavior is that shiny renders HTML elements with the same name `outputID`: 'CPlot', which is invalid to display, the only solution i know is to make the whole plot object reactive and assign it to unique outputIDs ( CPlot, DPlot, EPlot, FPlot)

#### full code example:

```
data <- as.data.frame(mtcars)

ui <- dashboardPage(
  skin = "yellow",
  dashboardHeader(title = "My dashboard"),
  dashboardSidebar(
    sidebarMenu()
  ),
  dashboardBody(
    fluidRow(
      box(title = "Primary Metric:", status = "primary", solidHeader = T, plotOutput("CPlot"), width = 7),
      box(selectInput("metric", 
                      "Metric:", 
                      c("mpg",  "cyl", "hp", "wt")),  
          width = 3
      )
    ),
    fluidRow(
      box(title = "Sub-Metric1", width = 4,  status = "warning", solidHeader = T, plotOutput("DPlot")),
      box(title = "Sub-Metric2", width = 4,  status = "warning", solidHeader = T, plotOutput("EPlot")),
      box(title = "Sub-Metric3", width = 4,  status = "warning", solidHeader = T, plotOutput("FPlot"))
    )
  )
)


server <- function(input, output){
  
  # plot
  Plot <- reactive({
    ggplot(data, aes(x=data[[input$metric]])) +
      geom_histogram(fill="#D55E00", color="#e9ecef", alpha=0.9) +
      labs(
        title = paste0("Distribution of ", paste0(input$metric), " over the last 12 month"),
        x = req(input$metric),
        y = "Count") +
      theme_minimal()
  }) %>% bindEvent(input$metric)
  
    output$CPlot <-output$DPlot <-output$EPlot <-output$FPlot <- renderPlot({Plot()})

  
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: Thanks @user12256545 for your helpful comment. I just had one more question that I appreciate your help: I want the second row to depend on the choice in the first row. For instance, if the user is choosing "mpg" I wand the second row to show three plots (e.g., "drat", "wt" ,  "qsec") but is she selects the "cyl" then only two plots appear in the second column (e.g., "gear", "carb").

Comment: i miss-interpreted your question then, You want to show one histogram in the main plot and the other three should show histograms of the other columns, depending on which were chosen?

Comment: No your answer is perfect for my first question. This is a follow up question, which I appreciate your thoughts on. I wanted to post it as a new question, but I thought you might have the answer.

Comment: i nevertheless edited it because i found a faster method to achieve the same by only rnedering the plot once