# Edit the HTML id attribute in a shiny UI without changing the outputId variable

Tags: html, r, shiny, attributes

#### Backgroud:

This question is a followup to [problem-with-r-shiny-dashboard-and-multiple-rows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76530408/problem-with-r-shiny-dashboard-and-multiple-rows/76530624#76530624)

The problem was, that shiny can create html objects using the same `outputId` variable, however this will result in two html objects using the same `id` attribute, which makes no sense and results in an silent error. The obvious solution was to render the object multiple times in the server function and assign those to individual `outputId` s. However this means unnecessary recomputing of the same code.

#### Consider following minimal reproducible example:

```
library(shiny)

ui <- tagList(
  plotOutput(outputId = "plot_id"),
  plotOutput(outputId = "plot_id")
  # ->adding a second plot using the same outputId will break things
)

server <- function(input, output){
  output$plot_id <- renderPlot({plot(1:10)})
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

#### Note:

`plotOutput(outputId = "plot_id")` will create following `HTML`:

```
<div class="shiny-plot-output html-fill-item" id="plot_id" style="width:100%;height:400px;"></div>
```

where the html attribute `id="plot_id"` is inherited from `outputId`.

#### Question:

Is there an elegant way to edit the html attribute id in the shiny `ui` without changing the `outputId` logic and thus reuse the same object multiple times in the UI without re-rendering?

#### what i tried:

I can edit the `ui` object:

```
ui[[2]]$attribs$id <- "plot_id2"
```

This results in the correct rendering of the first plot, and the space for the second plot is there but its not shown, because its not created from the server.

Comment: As the comment on the accepted answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45162511/using-the-same-output-element-twice-in-shiny) suggests, could you do  `output$plot_id <- output$plot_id2 <- renderPlot({plot(1:input$mx)})` and then use `plot_id` and `plot_id2` as output IDs?

Comment: While this workaround would work in this case, i will keep the question open nonetheless because i want to see if someone knows a general way to edit the `tag id`inside the ui